# Product of symplectic manifold is symplectic

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Assume ($M_1,\omega_1 $) and ($M_2,\omega_2)$ are symplectic manifolds. Consider $M_1\times M_2$. I want to show this is also symplectic manifold.

Let $p_1, p_2$ denote the projections. Then what I need is $p_1^*(\omega_1)^n \wedge p_2^*(\omega_2)^n$ is non-zero. I am stuck here. I guess $p_1^*(\omega_1 ^n)$ and $p_2^*(\omega_2 ^n)$ are both nonzero since $\omega_i ^n$ is nonzero by non degeneracy of $\omega_i$ and $p_i$ is submersion. But how do I know $p_1^*(\omega_1)^n \wedge p_2^*(\omega_2)^n$ is non-zero?

Comment: This is a general fact, more linear algebra than anything else: if $\omega_i$ are volume forms on $M_i$, then $p_1^*\omega_1\wedge p_2^*\omega_2$ is a volume form on $M_1 \times M_2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller So is there easy proof of this fact?

Comment: @user330928 Check pointwisely: in a coordinate $U_i$ of $M_i$, $\omega_i^n = f_i(x) dx_1\wedge \cdots\wedge dx_{n_i}$, where $n_i = \dim M_i$, how do you express $p_1^* w_1^n \wedge p_2^* w_2^n$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Cool. By the way, do you know any method without use local coordinates?

Comment: This is really a pointwise calculation, any method that use more than that is likely an overkill..... @user330928

Answer (score 3):

If $(M_1,\omega_1)$ and $(M_2,\omega_2)$ are symplectic manifolds then
$$
\omega:=p_1^\ast\omega_1+p_2^\ast\omega_2
$$
is a symplectic form on $M_1\times M_2$.  Then $\omega$ is closed since $d$ commutes with $p_1^\ast$ and $p_2^\ast$ and $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are closed.

To see that $\omega$ is nondegenerate, let $x:=(x_1,x_2)\in M_1\times M_2$ and let $(u_1,u_2)\in T_x(M_1\times M_2)$ be a nonzero element.  WLOG assume $u_1\neq 0$.  Then there exists $v_1\in T_{x_1}M_1$ such that $\omega_1(u_1,v_1)\neq 0$.  So
$$
\omega((u_1,u_2),(v_1,0))=\omega_1(u_1,v_1)+\omega(u_2,0)=\omega_1(u_1,v_1)\neq 0
$$